# Swipe Left/Right without breaking click or vertical swiping event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swipe

[image: Swiping]
<sub>(source: [maroonlemoon.com](http://maroonlemoon.com/mobile/bookintransit.png))</sub>

I am using jQuery Mobile/Javascript and HTML 5 to develop a web app. I want to achieve a touch scrolling event on smart devices. After Noticing that jQuery mobile's $(document).on("swipeleft and swiperight... keeps hanging on mobile devices, I used a javascript code snippet that uses vmousedown and vmouseup events, and this works decently but the problem is that when I use event.preventDefault, this breaks < a href="#bar"  clicks which have jQuery mobile navigation transitions. Also, the normal vertical scrolling gets broken with this code. Any idea how I can overcome this using the same javascript code (don't want to use jQuery mobile's swipe events)

```
//Javascript
var Page = 1;
        var gnStartX = 0;
        var gnStartY = 0;
        var gnEndX = 0;
        var gnEndY = 0;

        $("#pages-content").on('vmousedown',function(event){
            gnStartX = event.pageX;
            gnStartY = event.pageY;
            event.preventDefault(); 
            BindAll(); // this function binds div clicks inside #pages-content 
            // I want to re-bind normal vertical scrolling and any clicks on <a> tags with jQuery mobile transitions
        });

        $("#pages-content").on('vmouseup', function(event){
            gnEndX = event.pageX;
            gnEndY = event.pageY;  
            var distance = Math.ceil(nthroot(Math.pow((gnEndX - gnStartX),2) + Math.pow((gnEndY - gnStartY),2), 2));


            if(Math.abs(gnEndX - gnStartX) > Math.abs(gnEndY - gnStartY)) {
                if(gnEndX > gnStartX) {
                    if(Page>1) {
                        $('#pages-content').animate({"left":"+=100%"},function(){});
                        Page--;
                    }

                } else {
                    if(Page<4){
                        $('#pages-content').animate({"left":"-=100%"},function(){});   
                        Page++;
                    }

                }

            }
            event.preventDefault();   
            UpdatePageTitle(Page);
            BindAll();

        });

            function nthroot(x, n) {
              try {
                var negate = n % 2 == 1 && x < 0;
                if(negate)
                  x = -x;
                var possible = Math.pow(x, 1 / n);
                n = Math.pow(possible, n);
                if(Math.abs(x - n) < 1 && (x > 0 == n > 0))
                  return negate ? -possible : possible;
              } catch(e){}
            }


<!-- HTML Code
<div id="container" role="main" class="ui-content" style="overflow-x:hidden; padding:0px;">
    <div id="pages-content" style="position:relative;left:0%; width:500%; padding:1%;">
        <div id="page1" style="float:left; width:19.5%; padding-right:0.5%">
         <!-- This div may contain <a tags with href="" and with html5 transition attr
         </div>
         <div id="page2".... to page5
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your initial problem with swipeleft / right?

Comment: @NicolasR it's just very unresponsive. It works 1 out 10 times maybe on Android and not as smoothly as this piece of code (even after adjusting the sensitivity flags)

Comment: Ok. For your code, maybe you could try to do `event.preventDefault();` only when you change your page in the vmouseup event

Comment: @NicolasR tried that. It doesn't work. Doing so prevents the <a href=""> clicks on all content inside "pages-content

Comment: @NicolasR also swiping only works on my iPad/iPhone but not on any Android device if I add preventDefault on vmouseup only

Comment: Ok, please provide a full sample on jsfiddle (with your css / html structure) so that we can help & test

Comment: @NicolasR I just uploaded the code on the following link: http://maroonlemoon.com/mobile/mobile.rar

Comment: I can't test more at the moment (need to use another computer with more rights / tools). But the idea is around 2 things: the fact that you use preventDefault in some cases, and the fact that your vmouse is only on the pages-content div, so not working in the list item for example.

Comment: You're right @NicolasR. I also kind of want the event to be triggered only on pages-content div though. It's like this: you either click on the buttons in the list item, or you swipe the content itself to navigate. I really appreciate your time and efforts. If you find the time/were able to find a workaround for this, please let me know :) ~ Thanks again

Comment: I think the "pages-content scroll only" approach is not the good one: both your pages-content and list items should be able to throw the scroll. In fact, on the list items, it will depend on the distance between vmousedown and vmouseup: if small => it's a click, if big => it's a scroll

Comment: @NicolasR True, however this has no effect on the bigger problem of preventDefault messing other events up unfortunately.

Comment: I will try to look at this tonight if I can